# Realm.copyFromRealm cause Realm access from incorrect thread. is it possible?

Tags: java, android, realm

Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they where created.

I make alarm service by using realm DB.

Therefore, in order to get "time" data, I have to access to the object created in other thread.

So i copy realmlist like the source below, but illegalstateexception comes out at this part.

Is there other solution?

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

List<DayWorkType> dayWorkTypesCopied = realm.copyFromRealm(dayWorkTypes);
//FAILED HERE

realm.close();
```

Comment: can you paste the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before using `dayWorkTypes` you need to extract their ids and use them in a request from another Realm instance

```java
//in your first/main thread
Set<String> dayWorkTypeIds = dayWorkTypes.map(d -> d.getId());

...

//in your new thread just query realm
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
RealmResults<DayWorkType> dayWorkTypes2 = realm
        .where(DayWorkType.class)
        .in("id", dayWorkTypeIds.toArray(new String[0]);

//now you can use dayWorkTypes2 as you want in your thread
```

Comment: I used a solution similar to yours. Save parent's id and query realm. Then it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        try {
            List<DayWorkType> dayWorkTypesCopied = realm.copyFromRealm(dayWorkTypes);
        } finally {
            realm.close();
        }
    }
});

thread.start();
```

Comment: @jiba is this solution working ? Not sure because the problem is accessing `dayWorkTypes` from an incorrect thread